# How to write a script which automatically presses `Fn + F3` button on my keyboard

Tags: bash, scripts, brightness

I am struggling with screen brightness reset issues . It resets to 100% on every reboot. 
I have tried searching for solutions but none of them worked[including `xbacklight` ].

Since I can change screen brightness by pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> a couple of times , I was wondering if I could make a script do it on every reboot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Alternative way

Writing a script to press a key combination to set your screen's brightness seems a bit of a detour to me. You can directly set your screen brightness on log in by adding the command:

```
xrandr --output <your_screenname> --brightness 0.7
```

to your startup applications. Of course, instead of `0.7` (=70%), you can use any value you prefer.

Replace `<your_screenname>` by the actual name of your screen. Find out your screen's name by looking into the output of the command:

```
xrandr
```

Look for the word `connected`; the name before that is your screen's name

#### Add the command to your startup applications

Open Startup Applications (Dash > Startup Applications) and choose "Add". Add the command above and next time you log in, your screen's brightness will be set automaically to the value you defined in the command.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , it did change the brightness but the colors got slightly wierd. I mean , in the settings the brightness was still set to 100% and the brightness of the cursor was distinctly brighter than the rest of the screen.

I was looking for a proper reduction of screen brightness.
Anyway , your answer provided me some relief.

Answer (score 1):

The brightness of an Ubuntu system is maintained as numbers in 3 files `brightness`, `max_brightness` and `actual_brightness` in `/sys/class/backlight/<VGA>`directory.

Replace `<VGA>` with `intel_backlight` if you are having an Intel VGA card and `radeon_bl0` if you are having an AMD card.

You may check the value in the `max_brightness` file and based on that, set a value in the `brightness` file. So when the system reboots, the brightness actually resets to the value in the `brightness` file.

You won't be needing a custom script to reset brightness.

Comment: Unfortunately I am using AMD APU 8400 Card

Comment: what are the contents of `/sys/class/backlight` directory in your system?

Comment: It contains a directory named `radeon_bl0` which itself contains following `actual_brightness  brightness  max_brightness  subsystem  uevent
bl_power           device      power           type
`

Comment: good. Then you may follow my instructions to manipulate the `brightness` files in the `radeon_bl0` folder.

Comment: The max value is 253 and in brightness folder it is already 63.
But on restart I guess it resets!
Should I try changing the value in `max_brighntess` instead?

Comment: you can confirm if it's resetting by checking the value in  `actual_brightness` immediately after reboot

Comment: After reboot the file `brightness` is being reset to 255 (max brightness) .
As soon as I change the `brightness` value to 63 brightness changes.
Any way I can prevent `brightness` file being resetting every time on reboot?

Comment: You should not alter the value in `max_brightness` file. As per convention, brightness value = the value to which system resets to after reboot. max_brightness value = maximum brightness that one can go to. actual_brightness value = the current brightness of the system. To see live change to brightness, try changing the value in actual_brightness file. Once you get to a comfortable brightness set that value in brightness file and reboot and see if it is working or not.

Comment: Nopes , it resets to `max_brightness` every time I reboot!